# PATH priority and rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos, homebrew

I'm using Homebrew for OS X and have non-default ruby and rails installations on my system. I was performing a reinstall of those tools and found a curious problem.

When I run `rails` on my system it seems to be invoking the default version:

```
$ rails
Rails is not currently installed on this system. To get the latest version, simply type:

    $ sudo gem install rails

You can then rerun your "rails" command.
```

However, `which rails` shows the correct path:

```
$ which rails
/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.1.2/bin/rails
```

Likewise, `which -a rails` shows both paths:

```
$ which -a rails
/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.1.2/bin/rails
/usr/bin/rails
```

The unusual part being that I believe the `/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.1.2/bin/rails` should be executed instead of the `/usr/bin/rails` version. Invoking `/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.1.2/bin/rails --version` directly works:

```
$ /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.1.2/bin/rails --version
Rails 4.1.1
```

Why doesn't invoking `rails` run the version at `/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.1.2/bin/rails`? Is there something I'm missing? Here's my PATH variable for reference: `/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.1.2/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/X11/bin`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `brew doctor` if it doesn't fix the issue,
edit the `/etc/paths` to look like

```
/usr/local/bin
/usr/local/sbin
/usr/bin
/bin
/usr/sbin
/sbin
```

As described in [here](https://coderwall.com/p/w-zzpa)

Comment: Those were actually the first steps I tried. Does `/etc/paths` actually make a difference outside of the content of the PATH variable?

Comment: AFAIK only in mavericks